# How to measure noise, consonance, dissonance of a sound?

Tags: fft, audio, signal-analysis, noise, random

How can I make a graph of the noisiness of some audio durations of 100ms - 10s with 100% being white noise and 0% being a sine wave.

I have FFT at the moment, are there other ways to know the commensurate random nature and perhaps even the dissonance of sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are spectral peaks and you want to calculate the dissonance of this sound, you can calculate the *sensory dissonance*. See the [Essentia explanation](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/reference/std_Dissonance.html) and the references mentioned there.

If you rather want to measure how noisy a sound is, *spectral flatness* may be the audio feature of your choice. E.g. see this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_flatness).